# OwnerDrawText custom draw event triggers whenever Plus Minus sign in hovered over in a treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm having problems with a custom draw event for my treeview nodes. I draw nodes with tags using this event:

```
private void SoundBankSlotAssignmentTree_DrawNode( object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Name, TreeFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Top);
    if (e.Node.Tag != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Tag.ToString(), TreeTagFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right + 150, e.Bounds.Top);
    }
}
```

My problem is, whenever I hover over a PlusMinus sign displayed to the left of the node, the whole node is drawn again on top of the text that's already been drawn.

I use OwnerDrawText DrawMode and do not use any events on hover for neither the treeview, nor for the nodes. 
This is the only even I use for calling the draw:

```
this.SoundBankSlotAssignmentTree.DrawNode += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(this.Treeview_DrawNode);
```

I've been fighting with this issue for a couple of days already and didn't find a way to fix it.

When I disable the PlusMinus for the treeview, the issue goes away, but that's not the setup I'd like to use.

I would very much appreciate it if you could help me out with this one. 
Thanks!

Comment: The code is forgetting to draw the background so does not overdraw the old pixels.  Note the use of FillRectangle() in the [MSDN sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode(v=vs.110).aspx).  Not optional.

Comment: Thanks, I had some issues with the size of the rectangle I was supposed to feel, but figured this out thanks to you making me to look at this issue again. The code on MSDN page does not provide the size of the rectangle for the node not using a tag, so I had to make some changes there. It's fixed now, thanks for the help!